# Firebase Gplus login example?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

Is there any firebase G-plus authentication example that could be useful as firebase doesn't provide any information regarding G-plus auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Firebase quickstart for Android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) which has a `GoogleSignInActivity` class.

If you want to use Google Plus scopes, just modify the `GoogleSignInOptions` to do so.  Firebase Auth does not care what scopes you used when getting the `GoogleSignInAccount` object.

Also unless you want to know about the user's circles there is not much reason to use Plus scopes anymore.  You can get the user's name, email, and picture all with the default configuration.

Comment: I'm trying it.. thnks , n will let u know